# Pass jsonobject from swift4 to wkwebview JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, swift3, swift4

I have a function in swift that read a file content as string and convert that into json object using jsonserialization. I want to pass that json object to wkwebview JavaScript function as object. So that I can access the data from JavaScript.

Iam using the evaluatescript method of swift

Answer (score 3):

I have solved the issue by

**Swift Code**

```
func readFromFile(_ fileurl: String) {
    var myData:String = "";
    do {
        let url = NSURL(string: fileurl.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)!)
        myData = try String(contentsOf: url! as URL)
        let data = myData.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!
        do {
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! [String: AnyObject]
            let serializedData = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json, options: .prettyPrinted)
            let encodedData = serializedData.base64EncodedString(options:.endLineWithLineFeed)
            let js2:String = "LoadJson('\(encodedData)')"
            self.wkWebView?.evaluateJavaScript(js2, completionHandler: { (AnyObject, NSError) -> Void in
                NSLog("%s", #function)
                self.showMessage("Loaded")
            })
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Failed to load: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    } catch{
        showMessage("Loading error.");
    }
}
```

**Javascript code**

```
function LoadJson (encodedData) {
   try {
      var decodedData = window.atob(encodedData);
      jsonObj = JSON.parse(decodedData);
   }
   catch (err) {
   }
}
```